# How create @Directive from @Component spinner

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a component **SpinnerComponent**. I want to make a *@Directive* from **SpinnerComponent**. How do I do this? My code:

**spinner.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'spinner',
  template: require('./spinner.html'),
})

export class SpinnerComponent {}
```

**loader.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
  public status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  display(value: boolean) {
    this.status.next(value);
  }
}
```

**Then I use it like this in OtherComponent:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loaderService.status.subscribe(status => {
      this.isLoadingData = status;
    });
  }
```

**Template**

```
<spinner></spinner>
```

Comment: what did you try and what is the error you are facing??

Comment: I cannot get the question, what do you mean to get a directive from component?